# .ssh " Problema con carpeta .ssh " no aparece x ningún lado

Tags: ssh, git-bash

Amigos cree una llave con
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4069 -C "miCorreo"`  y se supone que debía crearme automáticamente la carpeta .ssh pero no la creo y no aparece en ningún lado la carpeta, que puedo hacer ?

Comment: intenta buscar el `cd ~/.ssh/` por cierto te invito a hacer el [tour]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 ¿estás en Windows, alguna distro linuxera, Mac?

Comment: En qué OS estás? Si usas git bash, asumimos que es windows? Recuerda que el explorador por defecto oculta las carpetas del sistema y de configuración, como `.ssh`

Comment: si estoy en windows , y no esta oculta y tampoco aparece al buscarla con cd ~/.ssh/

Comment: Amigo que tal soluciono su problema ? yo tampoco consigo la carpeta por ningun lado y se creo correctamente

Comment: @DeninsonLopez agregue una respuesta aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/578923/problema-con-carpeta-ssh-no-aparece-x-ning%c3%ban-lado-a-pesar-que-la-cree-exitosa/578943#578943

Answer (score 0):

De forma predeterminada el archivo se guarda en el directorio `$HOME\.ssh` que sería:

```
C:\Users\<usuario>\.ssh
```

aquí puedes encontrar tu archivo.