# . Problema con carpeta .ssh no aparece x ningún lado a pesar que la cree exitosamente

Tags: git

Cree la llave todo bien me da la ruta donde la guardo me dice que todo bien pero cuando voy a la ruta no aparece la carpeta ni la lleve por mas que la busco por todo el sistema.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4069 -C "miCorreo"
```

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias

Previamente, revise esta pregunta:

[.ssh " Problema con carpeta .ssh " no aparece x ningún lado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442736/ssh-problema-con-carpeta-ssh-no-aparece-x-ning%c3%ban-lado)

Comment: Bienvenido a SO! Podrías colocar los comandos y las salidas en la pregunta (como texto)?

Comment: ¿Cuando hablar de *ir a la ruta* a qué te refieres? ¿Tienes activada la visibilidad de los archivos / carpetas ocultos? Si no lo tienes activado no verás la carpeta.

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda revisar [ask] para realizar tus preguntas, agrega siempre información que ayude a solucionar el problema, saludos.

Comment: `ls -hal ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

De forma predeterminada el archivo se guarda en el directorio:

```
C:\Users\<usuario>\.ssh
```

Ahí puedes buscar tus archivos.

---

Si deseas cambiar la ruta donde creas el archivo, agrega la opción -f , por ejemplo:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "jorgesys@gmail.com" -f C:\Users\jorgesys\keys\jorgesys_id_rsa
```

[image: jorgesys ssh keygen]

Busca tus archivos en el directorio que definiste y podrás ver que fueron creados:

[image: jorgesys ssh keygen]